# What is the application on screen in this post?

Tags: web-apps, maps

This 9gag post is a recording of some application (web app potentially) which allows to look at russo ukrainian war map with the ability of picking timeframe from timeline at the top.

It is not liveuamap application nor it is deepstate map.

Can anyone recognize this application?

[image: image of some sort of war-map application]

https://9gag.com/gag/aDYXbgK

Comment: Looks like DeepState Live, a web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked posts seems to be from a web app using OpenStreemap data as base with some overlays.

I'd say it is from NewsMap polish website at

https://newsmap.pl/2022-russian-invasion-of-ukraine-interactive-map/

There is a time line over the top you can drag left and right to seem a real time update of the events on the map